# will this query alternative to join (simple) work?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

the link is
http://www.sqlcommands.net/sql+join/

i would like to know if it would work if it were

```
SELECT Weather.City
FROM Weather
WHERE Weather.City = State.City
```

meaning select all those cities "from weather" which belong in the state table

will the above work if not then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or, as an alternative (using yr english sentence as a guide):

```
SELECT City                -- select all those cities
FROM Weather               -- "from weather"
Where City In              -- which 
  (Select City From State) -- belong in the state table
```

Answer (score 2):

No because to use State.City, the table State needs to be somewhere in the FROM list.

The alternate to the example you provided would be:

```
SELECT Weather.City
FROM Weather
INNER JOIN State
ON Weather.City = State.City
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query won't work because the table `State` does not appear in the FROM clause so you can't reference its columns.

This would work though:

```
SELECT Weather.City
FROM Weather
JOIN State
ON Weather.City = State.City
```